# How to access the predictions made in scikit-learn's GridSearchCV-function?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, cross-validation

I'm using scikit-learn's GridSearchCV to implement hyperparameter tuning for a classifier model. As I've understood from the documentation of [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html), you can query for attributes such as best estimator, best score, et cetera, but I would be interested in getting the predicted y-class labels which were used to calculate the best score attribute in GridSearchCV.

Is there a way to access these predictions?

Comment: `your_grid_search_cv.predict(X_train)`?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Thank you for your comment. To my understanding though, the predictions made in the approach you suggested do not unfortunately correspond to the `best_score_`-attribute of the GridSearchCV. Please correct me if I am wrong :)

Comment: as you can read from the documentation "_ cross-validated grid-search_" therefore there is no notion of "validation set" since the whole training set is used as validation, holding out pieces of it each time

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia yes, I am interested exactly in these "pieces of data held-out", because these are used to calculate the score. I would be interested in having access to these (I'm comparing my own algorithm to scikit-learn's and this is why I need more details on the predictions). But did I understand, that the answer to my question is "no"?

Comment: you might want to read what is _cross validation_ online, so you can understand that what you are asking makes little to no sense

Comment: the training set is split in K parts, K copies of the classifier are trained in K-1 subsets, and the last one is used as validation, and the final score is the average of those K evaluations

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I understand completely and in-depth level of what cross-validation is having coded multiple versions of it myself for many years now. I might have explained myself unclearly. Cross-validation usually in its basic form goes like this simplified: Iteration 1: train with train subset 1 --> predict test subset 1 --> get score for test subset 1 --> go to next iteration. In the end, collect the scores, average them or something else similar and report. I need access to the predictions in the **predict test subset i** phases.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Can you clarify what part of my question did not make sense, if after my elaboration still did not make it clear? :)

Comment: _Iteration 1: train with train subset 1_... no, it trains with everything except subsets 1, and use subsets 1 to validate